# Any way to avoid this probably unnecessary query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I have this lines in my controller:

```
 if Account.includes(:student).where(:email => account[:email]).any?
      student=Account.find_by_email(account[:email]).student
      @stream.students << student
      else
        #...
      end
```

here I suppose it makes two db queries instead of one, for condition, and inside, if true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going from memory and typing on an iPad but I think you can do something like:

```
if student = Student.joins(:account).find_by(accounts: { email: account[:email] })
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
student = Account.includes(:student).where(:email => account[:email]).first
if student
# code
```

`first` returns the first record or nil which if nil will fail the if statement.

Comment: Doesn't this create the student as an instance of Account?

Comment: Yea, the answer above is correct, I read the question wrong initially.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following codes will make it:

```
student_account = Account.includes(:student).where(:email => account[:email]).first
if !student_account.nil?
  student=student_account.student
  @stream.students << student
else
    #...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd look to restructure as:

```
if student = Student.joins(:accounts).
                     where(:accounts => {:email => account[:email]}).
                     take
  @stream.students << student
  else
    #...
  end
```

I'm making some guesses here about your models and associations, of course, but this is a single query that returns a Student.

Comment: This returns a relation and not a single student object as described

Comment: Well spotted -- needs a tweak I guess.